# matlab train set UCI

Tags: matlab

I'm being required to train a perceptron in Matlab to learn a classification data set (any, really). The only restriction is that the data set must come from the UCI Machine Learning Repository. The problem is that I have really no idea where to begin as my teacher is extremely bad at what he does and never explained it well. I've tried asking other class-mates for help but none of them seem to have the answers. I hope I can get help from this community as it's my last chance. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we're really not your last chance. There are plenty of tutorials, examples, and resources findable easily from Google that would help (for example, search on "MATLAB perceptron iris" - the iris dataset is a famous example dataset, included in the UCI repository).

But here's a start. I'm assuming that if you've been set the task of training a perceptron in MATLAB, then you have access to Neural Network Toolbox (if you're asking how to *implement* a perceptron algorithm from scratch in MATLAB, look in a textbook).

Type `doc nnet`. That will bring up the documentation for Neural Network Toolbox. Then click through to the section labelled "Examples". Scrolling down to the bottom, there are several demos in a section called "Perceptrons". Try looking at the demos "Classification with a 2-Input Perceptron" or "Linearly Non-separable Vectors". Those demos use toy datasets, but should give you an idea of how to train a perceptron.

Then scroll up to the section "Pattern Recognition and Classification", and take a look at the demo "Wine Classification". The Wine dataset this demo uses is part of the UCI repository. Adapt and combine the demos you've now learnt from, to create an example your prof will like.

Neural Network Toolbox also comes with the Iris dataset that is part of the UCI repository. You may also find a demo somewhere that uses this as an example.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello Mr, your post has been very helpful to me and now I put together some code. I explained it better in this other topic of mine. Please, if you would be so kind to check it out as I am encountering a few problems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743530/matlab-train-data-set